# Accessing id field of Mongo document raises "TypeError: need one of hex, bytes, bytes_le, fields, or int"

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

I want to add a record for the document and then get the generated id.  However, I get the error `TypeError: need one of hex, bytes, bytes_le, fields, or int` when I try to access `user_id`.  Why am I getting this error?

```
class User(db.DynamicDocument):
    user_id = db.UUIDField(primary_key=True, required=True, default=uuid.UUID)
    ...

user = User().save()
user_id = user.user_id
```

```
File "views.py", line 15, in post
    user = User().save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 96, in __init__
    setattr(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 188, in __setattr__
    super(BaseDocument, self).__setattr__(name, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 123, in __set__
    value = value()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise TypeError('need one of hex, bytes, bytes_le, fields, or int')
TypeError: need one of hex, bytes, bytes_le, fields, or int
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is with the default value of `user_id`.  Set the default to `uuid.uuid4`, which will generate `UUID` objects.

```
class User(db.DynamicDocument):
    user_id = db.UUIDField(primary_key=True, required=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    ...
```